# ADB device not found - Samsung galaxy S3 with Custom ROM

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, windows, usb-drivers, cyanogenmod, att

I'm trying to test ADB in samsung device thru USB. It is working as expected in Ubuntu and MAC OS. 
In Windows7, Im getting "error:device not found" in phone mode, but the phone is getting detected in recovery mode.

Model: samsung sgh i747
android: 4.4.4
CM version CM11- M12 -d2lte

I tried deleting the UpperFilter in regedit and reinstalled the driver more than a few times. (http://www.onger.net/?p=1401)

Samsung device with stock rom is working as usual.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]